R Markdown PDF slides: insert image above author on title slide
In R Markdown compiling to PDF slides, how do I include an image immediately below the title (i.e. above the author) on the title slide?
This post suggests it may be possible using the titling package, but I get an 'undefined control sequence' error for \if@titlepage.
Here's my MWE:
---
title: "Your Presentation Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \preauthor{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{images/my-title-image}\LARGE\\}
  - \postauthor{\end{center}}
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1

Content here.

# Section 2

## Slide 2

More content here.


And the error I get is:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.35 \if@titlepage

Any suggestions?

Don't use the titling package with beamer. Beamer has its own mechanism to build the title page.
If your beamer version is up-to-date, you can simply add your image to the author template:
---
title: "Your Presentation Title"
author: "Your Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
header-includes:
  - \addtobeamertemplate{author}{\centering\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\par}{}
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1

Content here.

# Section 2

## Slide 2

More content here.



Thanks - is there a route that works for older versions of beamer? (I'm on a corporate computer running TeX Live version 2017! Will try to get it updated but I don't like my chances...)

@jms202 Texlive can also be installed as a portable version e.g. on a thumb drive. Then you can enjoy all the new beamer features added since 2017.

I'd love to do this but the laptop is locked down for security reasons, so I can't easily use a thumb drive or move the data and code to a different laptop. Is there no way of achieving it using the ancient beamer I've got access to?
